# why are bernoulli's equation non-linear

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

So i was studying linear algebra and I learned about linear transformations and their definitions. In the applications of linear transformations i learnt that in linear differential equation the differential operator can be treated as a linear transformation from a vector space of differentiable functions in a given interval to itself
                       T(y)=Q 
where 'T' is the differential operator & Q is a function of x. But a Bernoulli's equation which is of the form
                       T(y)=Q*y^n 
is not considered a linear equation. Why is that? The transformation still seems linear to me. The only difference I see is that we are looking for a function which is being mapped to its own nth power. How does that makes the transformation non-linear

Comment: For $T$ to be a linear transformation, it must be that $T(y+z)=T(y)+T(z)$

Comment: " The transformation still seems linear to me": can you explain your understanding of *linear* ?

Comment: T(aX+bY)=aT(X)+bT(Y) I understand the definition of linear transformation. What I am trying to understand is the difference between a linear dfifferential equation and Bernoulli's differential equation.In the first equation  T(y)=Q we want to solve for y which after the transformation T is mapped to Q. In the second equation T(y)= Q*y^n we are looking for y which after the transformation T is mapped to Q*y^n.How does that makes the transformation T non-linear? Doesn't Q*y^n lie in the range space of T. I hope I made my doubt clear

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, if you write the Bernoulli equation $y'=Py+Qy^n$ as $$T[y]=Qy^n~~\text{ with }~~T[y]=y'-Py,$$ the left side $T[y]$ is linear. However, the full equation is non-linear, as the power on the right side is not linear.

If it were linear, then with any solution $y$, also any multiple $\alpha y$ would be a solution. However that would imply that $α^{n-1}=1$, which is not valid for almost all $α$.